# How to check all collections in Mongo database to find field name exists in which collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have list of field names in a file "field_name_list.txt". I want to know which field exists in which collection in Mongo database using Java script or MapReduce job or some Mongo code.

Let me give example

field_name_list.txt

```
Firstname 
lastname
Address
zip
```

Collection in the database:

```
personal_data
adress
```

I want output like below:

```
Fieldname      collection_name 

Firstname      personal_data

lastname       personal_data

Address        Address

zipcode        Address
```

Comment: OK, so, what what you tried/where have you gotten stuck? As MongoDB is schema-less, you'll need to loop through every document to determine what fields exist for each collection.

Comment: Please stop asking the same question. Just edit the original question if you want to add additional clarification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006980/how-to-add-collection-name-in-the-output-of-map-reduce-job-to-get-all-the-keys-i?noredirect=1#comment26707948_18006980

Comment: I have a code to get all the field names in all collections of the datatbase.But there to no way to print collection name with field name .Thats why i have changed my logic once get the fields then based on filed name to get collection name using $exists function in mongo.Please help me if you have any idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection